# QWidgetAttribute for QWindow

Tags: qt

dose anyone know how to convert Qt::WidgetAttribute to Qt::WindowFlags???
and by convert i mean is there any WidgetAttribute like WA_NoBackground or WA_TranslucentBackground as a flag for WindowFlags....???

i've been trying to transparent my ApplicationWindow Item in QML but i couldn't.

Main.Qml

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
     title: qsTr("Hello World")
     width: 640
     height: 480
     flags: Qt.SubWindow | Qt.Tool | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
     opacity: 0.5
     Image {
           anchors.fill: parent
           source: "blah.png" // and this picture in transparent
     }
}
```

and know im looking for the flag that works like WA_NoBackground and WA_TranslucentBackground

Main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     Application app(argc, argv);

     QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
     engine.load(QUrl("blah.qml"));

     QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
     QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);

     window->show();
     window->setColor(Qt::transparent);

     return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: That's because transparency support is broken in Windows. You can check out my `QuickWidget` example and fix it to work under Windows. Otherwise, this is a famous Qt bug.